# ClassName becomes undefined after toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code. When I "toggle thumbs-up glyphicon" and try to get value of its class name on click of downvote button. It gives undefined value.

P.s. When I try to get its value in its own function, it works fine.

```
 <div style="float:right">
     <a class="upvotebtn" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>10000</a>
     <a class="downvotebtn" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i>10000</a>
</div>

$('.upvotebtn').click(function(){
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-thumbs-o-up').toggleClass('fa-thumbs-up');
    $(this).toggleClass('upvotebtn').toggleClass('upvotebtn-highlight');
});

$('.downvotebtn').click(function(){
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-thumbs-o-down').toggleClass('fa-thumbs-down');
        $(this).toggleClass('downvotebtn').toggleClass('downvotebtn-highlight');     
});
```

Comment: Event handlers are initialized on the elements that match the selector at the time they are executed, changing the classes doesn't later doesn't affect the event handlers.

Comment: see my answer this is that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the class of the button and then attempting to select by that class.  That won't work.  Instead, toggle a class that you don't use in the selector.  For example:

```
$('.upvotebtn').click(function(){
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-thumbs-o-up').toggleClass('fa-thumbs-up');
    $(this).toggleClass('upvotebtn-highlight');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set event handlers using `.on`, as it is dynamic in nature. Also you can pass multiple classes in single `.toggleClass`

```
$(document).on("click", '.upvotebtn', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('upvotebtn upvotebtn-highlight').find('i').toggleClass('fa-thumbs-o-up fa-thumbs-up');

});
$(document).on("click", '.downvotebtn', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('downvotebtn downvotebtn-highlight').find('i').toggleClass('fa-thumbs-o-down fa-thumbs-down');
});
```

Moreover, i really doubt that the classes you are toggling are not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.upvotebtn').click(function(){
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-thumbs-o-up fa-thumbs-up');
    $(this).toggleClass('upvotebtn upvotebtn-highlight');
  });

  $('.downvotebtn').click(function(){
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-thumbs-o-down fa-thumbs-down');
    $(this).toggleClass('downvotebtn downvotebtn-highlight');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="float:right">
     <a class="upvotebtn" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>10000</a>
     <a class="downvotebtn" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i>10000</a>
</div>
```